# Regular expressions in C preprocessor macro

Tags: c, regex, macros

I would like to know if there is any kind of regular expression expansion within the compiler(GCC) pre processor. Basically more flexible code generation macros.

If there is not a way, how do you suggest i accomplish the same result

Comment: Someone might know of a workaround if you gave more details of the actual problem.

Comment: I have multiple cases where it be usefull such thing. For instance taking a bunch of enum members and automagicaly create a switch statement of the them so that even if a member is added the code is updated with a default implementation  or with an #error. If you find this is really important information i will put it in the question

Comment: @aiwarrior - for your the specified problem above - you could use [X-macro](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor#X-Macros) trick to generate ENUM's and SWITCH statements alltogether. Also you can read about x-macros in this [e-book](http://www.keithschwarz.com/coursereader.pdf) - page 173 - "Practical Applications of the Preprocessor II: The X Macro Trick".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C preprocessor can't do that.

You might want to use a template processor (for instance [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) but there are many others) that generates what you need before passing it to the compiler.

Comment: this is indeed something that i have never heard of and looks like it would help a lot. I will wait for some more answers to see if there is an other solution

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are planning a bigger project and you know this feature will be beneficial you might want to write your own preprocessor that you can run automatically from some build system. Good example of such solution would be [moc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/moc.html) which enhances C++ for the purpose of Qt framework. Purist might of course disagree.

Comment: I'm not purist and I disagree. qmake has nothing to do with Qt's preprocessing of C++. It's moc! doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/moc.html

Comment: while i dont agree with the opaque way qmake works in regard to the language itself that would a project in itself and i dont need so much firepower

Comment: Of course I was thinking of moc .. my bad! Need more sleep. ;-)

Comment: the link to moc is broken

Answer (score 0):

There is this https://github.com/graph/qc qc = Quick C it allows you to do this in your source code files that end with qc.h

```
$replace asdf_(\d+) => asdf_ :) $1 blabla

// and now in your code anything that matches the above regular expression
asdf_123
// will become asdf_ :) 123 blabla
```

And it will output a .cpp & a .h thats preprocessed. Its made to avoid the need to maintain header files. And some other things not making it backwards compatible with c++, but it outputs c++ code so you can do all the c++ things you want at the end of the day.

Edit: I made it and have a bias towards qc.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at re2c.org.  It it a separate C preprocessor to generate
C code to match regular expressions.  I found that and your question when looking for
something similar.